# RVM and/or Bundler: ERROR: Missing RVM environment file…

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

Just upgraded to **RVM** `1.23.4` and **rubygems** `2.1.8` now getting this error:

```
$ bundle update
ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/meltemi/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p0'
```

I haven't had `2.0.0-p0` installed for months...

```
$ rvm list 

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-rc2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I'm not sure what's going on exactly. Anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:** I've just noticed that since the update `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global` is now a symlink. This wasn't the case before as `ruby-2.0.0-p247@global` used to be a standard directory.

```
~/.rvm/gems $ ls -l
. . .
drwxr-xr-x   8 meltemi  staff  272 May 13 18:12 ruby-2.0.0-p247
drwxr-xr-x  10 meltemi  staff  340 Jun 25 12:17 ruby-2.0.0-p247@app1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 meltemi  staff   62 Oct 11 09:15 ruby-2.0.0-p247@global -> /Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
drwxr-xr-x   8 meltemi  staff  272 May 13 18:40 ruby-2.0.0-p247@someapp
drwxr-xr-x   8 meltemi  staff  272 Mar  1  2013 ruby-2.0.0-p247@someotherapp
drwxr-xr-x   2 meltemi  staff   68 Aug  9  2010 ruby-head
```

So what's happened is I've lost my `global` gemset and all the gems `rubygems-bunder`, etc. that were in it!?!

**How did this happen?** Any way to recover?

Comment: what do you see with: `which bundle`
the `bundle` and `@global` are two separate questions most likely not related please remove the `@global` part - and open rvm issue for it => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Answer (score 0):

You seems like create ruby-2.0.0-p0 environment file.

I not sure why don't you have that file(maybe deleted in accident).

Below is my ruby-2.0.0-p0 file. 
You can use it after modify path as your own.

```
export PATH ; PATH="/Users/humbroll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/humbroll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/humbroll/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/humbroll/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
export rvm_env_string ; rvm_env_string='ruby-2.0.0-p0'
export rvm_path ; rvm_path='/Users/humbroll/.rvm'
export rvm_ruby_string ; rvm_ruby_string='ruby-2.0.0-p0'
unset rvm_gemset_name
export RUBY_VERSION ; RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.0.0-p0'
export GEM_HOME ; GEM_HOME='/Users/humbroll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0'
export GEM_PATH ; GEM_PATH='/Users/humbroll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/humbroll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME ; MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/humbroll/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0'
export IRBRC ; IRBRC='/Users/humbroll/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
```

Comment: This is interesting but I don't have `ruby-2.0.0-p0` installed anymore; haven't for months. I'm using `ruby-2.0.0-p247`, as you should be as well...

Answer (score 0):

You may have an outdated file in  `/Users/meltemi/.rvm/bin/`, maybe it's the `bundle` file.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28514833/115005) for more ideas.