# ERROR: Missing RVM environment file After Doing rvm upgrade command - Passenger 4.0.23

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, passenger

I was running ruby 2.0.0-p247 on my Mac Mini Server (Mavericks 10.9.1).  I read that there was a security vulnerability so I decided to upgrade to use the latest Ruby patch 2.0.0-p353.  I did the following commands:

```
gem update --system (RubyGems 2.1.11)
rvm get stable (RVM 1.25.0)
rvm upgrade 2.0.0-p247 2.0.0-p353 (which should have moved my gemsets)
```

There is nothing in my system that I can find that references 2.0.0-p247 in rvm which is what I expected.  When I go to ~/myuser/.rvm/environments there is no file 2.0.0-p247.

I am now attempting to start passenger.  I had version 4.0.23 enterprise installed.  I attempted to run `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module` but got an error.

```
cd /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mygemset/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.23
/Users/myuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ mygemset/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
# /Users/myuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ mygemset/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/Users/myuser/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247@LightBeCorp_Rails4Ruby2'
```

Here are statements in my .bashrc file related to rvm if this will help.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@mygemset/bin:/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby:/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby:/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby:/usr/bin/psql:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
```

I did a `rvm list rubies` command.  ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not listed.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will continue looking.  I plan to post a link to this in the Phusion Passenger group.

**UPDATE 12/21/2013 12:20 pm**

I updated my .bashrc file to the following since I no longer use the other rubies in my Rails applications.  I still get the error when I try to run `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module`.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby:/usr/bin/psql:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like a bug, please open a ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

---

Indeed this was a bug, to fix it run:

```
rvm get head
rvm gemset reset_env
```

you can repeat the `reset_env` operation for every gemset that is broken:

```
rvm ruby@gemset do rvm gemset reset_env
```

Comment: done.  I have included the link to this updated blog post in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a cached bin file in your RVM path. In my case, it's "/usr/local/rvm/bin/unicorn"

Also, you may not directly having the gem in your Gemfile. In my case, I do not have "unicorn" in my Gemfile although I had "capistrano-unicorn".

So that the system will try to use the global cached file "/usr/local/rvm/bin/unicorn".

The file's content may using a ruby that you no longer use.

```
if [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247" ]]
then
  source "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
  exec unicorn "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.0.0-p247'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```