# Web application could not be started Passenger Error (Apache2) - Referencing Non-Existing Ruby Patch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apache2, rvm, passenger

I have been having problems after updating from p247 to the latest patch for Ruby 2.0.0 (P353) using the latest version of RVM.  Here is the link to my original question where I was experiencing a missing RVN environment file for the old patch which was no longer in my system.  RVM was corrected and that problem disappeared.

[ERROR: Missing RVM environment file After Doing rvm upgrade command - Passenger 4.0.23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704890/error-missing-rvm-environment-file-after-doing-rvm-upgrade-command-passenger)

I went ahead and installed the latest version of Passenger 4.0.29 using the gem file in my Passenger Enterprise account.  I was able to install the passenger-install-apache2-module.  However I'm getting another error when I try to launch my applications.

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signaling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.

Raw process output:

/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@LightBeCorp_Rails4Ruby2/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

It looks like there is still a problem with referencing p247 when it is no longer in my system.  P247 only shows up on the Passenger error page in the statement I posted above.  Every other reference is for p353.  My guess is that it may be in the parser.bundle file.  However I do not know what editor to use to open it.  I tried Xcode but got nowhere.

Here are my Passenger statements in the config file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mygemset/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.29/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mygemset/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-4.0.29
PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/myusername/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mygemset/ruby
PassengerDebugLogFile /var/log/apache2/passenger_error_log
```

Here is a sample of my virtual hosts that I'm using for all my Rails applications.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.myrailsdomain.com
  ServerAlias myrailsdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp/public
  PassengerAppRoot /Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp/
  PassengerRuby /Users/myusername/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mygemset/ruby
  <Directory /Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp/public>
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the output from passenger-status:

```
Version : 4.0.29
Date    : 2013-12-22 11:58:13 -0600
Instance: 330
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp1/#default:
  App root: /Users/server1/Sites/myrailsapp1/
  Requests in queue: 0

/Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp2/#default:
  App root: /Users/server1/Sites/myrailsapp2/
  Requests in queue: 0

/Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp3/#default:
  App root: /Users/server1/Sites/myrailsapp3/
  Requests in queue: 0
```

After looking at the config files that I referenced in my previous post and what I have looked at here so far I cannot find anything that references patch p247.  I do know where this is coming from.  I have not found anything online regarding a problem with two different Ruby patches being referenced when one does not exist in the system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
cd /Users/myusername/Sites/myrailsapp
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@LightBeCorp_Rails4Ruby2
```

Now try to clean gems:

```
rvm gemset pristine
```

If this does not work run:

```
rvm gemset empty
bundle install
```

After that you might need to install any extra gems that were part of this gemset (ex. `passenger`)

Comment: I did the second suggestion, reinstalled Passenger and rebooted my server.  I then cleaned all the cache from my browser.  Unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: how about `otool -L /Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@LightBeCorp_Rails4Ruby2/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle` maybe you need to run: `rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353@LightBeCorp_Rails4Ruby2 ; rvm gemset pristine`

Comment: I executed the tool command, rvm gemset pristine and reinstalled Passenger.  The problem was solved and I'm able to host my Rails applications.  If you post your last comment as an answer I will check it.  Thanks so much.  I think when I do this on my production server I will just remove and reinstall RVM since I'm only using one gemset.  How do I remove RVM?

Comment: I could not find anything on the RVM website.  Can I just delete the .rvm folder and start over?

Comment: I just found the answer about removing .rvm.  I did a search and saw it was on the FAQ page for question 'Where is everything installed to?'.  I originally asked the question because there was not a section in the site map stating Removing RVM or something like that :)

Comment: fixed to your application gemset